# convert txt file to json file in C# console application

Tags: c#, json, txt

[image]

> I need to convert .txt file to j son file in C# console app

Comment: and what have you ***tried yourself so far***? please show your current efforts and share what specific problems you have.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, please don't post a problem statement as an image.

Answer (score 1):

If you have such a text file

> 1|name1|lastname1|test1@test.com|127.0.0.1
>
> 2|name2|lastname2|test2@test.com|127.0.0.2
>
> 3|name3|lastname3|test3@test.com|127.0.0.3

You can convert it to json with the following code

```
var filename = "C:\\1.txt";
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);

var model = lines.Select(p => new
{
    Id = p.Split("|")[0],
    FirstName = p.Split("|")[1],
    LastName = p.Split("|")[2],
    Email = p.Split("|")[3],
    Ip = p.Split("|")[4],
});
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(model);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make class or struct `User`, make constructor for this and deserialize this class. I prefer to use classes.

Class example:

```
class User
{
  public int id;
  public string name;
  public string surname;
  public string email;
  public string gender;
  public string IPAddress;
}
```

```
string split = YOUR_TXT_FILE_STRING.Split('|'); //Splitting file
User user = new User(split[0], split[1], split[2], split[3], split[4, split[5]]);
string output = JsonSerializer.Serialize(user, true); //Deserializing class
```

And now you can write `output` into text file again

**Usefull links:**

- https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0
- https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=net-5.0

It is easiest way you can do.